# Ethernet not working (enp9s0) Ubuntu: 16.04

Tags: networking, ethernet

When I do ifconfig, it shows this:

```
enp9s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f0:76:1c:f1:70:3a  
UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
RX packets:39 errors:0 dropped:3 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:111 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
RX bytes:6029 (6.0 KB)  TX bytes:12022 (12.0 KB)
```

I have Ethernet at college and it requires to sign in for all the pages outside. I can visit the pages with the domain .iitk.ac.in but none outside as the sign in page fails to come up. sudo ifup enp9s0 gives the following:

```
sudo ifup enp9s0
Unknown interface enp9s0
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Please contact the IT department.

Comment: No, it works for everyone. Just not on my laptop. And it used to work earlier but I had to install ubuntu again, and since then it doesn't now.